# mysql crash after ~ 1 day

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

i use a really small VPS as development server for a wordpress installation. The facts: 512mb RAM, Ubuntu 16.04, nginx server.

After using wordpress for a couple hours (till day) the mysql-server crashes and the logs say this:

```
2020-05-05T04:00:28.886012Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2020-05-05T04:00:28.886079Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2020-05-05T04:00:29.141722Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-05-05T04:00:29.148643Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 2299 ...
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166550Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166579Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166584Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166591Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166599Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-05T04:00:29.166909Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-05T04:00:29.167122Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-05-05T04:00:29.169383Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 32M, instances = 1, chunk size = 32M
2020-05-05T04:00:29.171692Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-05T04:00:29.186015Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-05-05T04:00:29.214017Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.214576Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 9778264
2020-05-05T04:00:29.214587Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 9778273
2020-05-05T04:00:29.214593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-05-05T04:00:29.214598Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.345046Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-05-05T04:00:29.345087Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-05T04:00:29.345132Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-05T04:00:29.369092Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.371891Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.371905Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.372154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-05T04:00:29.422351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 9778273
2020-05-05T04:00:29.422714Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.432421Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.432439Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.435161Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.435205Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.435276Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2020-05-05T04:00:29.435317Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2020-05-05T04:00:29.435345Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-05-05T04:00:29.446158Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-05T04:00:29.464315Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200505  6:00:29
2020-05-05T04:00:29.477252Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-05-05T04:00:29.490104Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

I already found posts here, which explain the same problem, but the solutions did work for me. I already changed the innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Include how you have minimized the ram of nginx, php and mysql? How much do each use? `dmesg` output might list how the OOM decided which to kill an how much where used at time of exhaustion? somethings you just can't run stuff on so small of resources. so idea; run with more ram. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

From Google, these are your MINIMUM requirements,

NGINX Controller requires the following minimum hardware specifications: RAM: 8 GB RAM. CPU: 8-Core CPU @ 2.40 GHz or similar. Disk space: 80 GB free disk space.

A 512MB server will not get the job done.